# Is it possible to convert a Ruby script to an .exe so that the source code is not visible?

Tags: windows, ruby, linux

Is it possible to convert a Ruby script to an .exe so that the source code is not visible?

Comment: What on Earth would you want to do that for?

Comment: He wants to hide the source, it is pretty obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use RubyScript2Exe, your source code can always be read. The explanation is in "[Tips & Tricks](http://www.erikveen.dds.nl/rubyscript2exe/#3.4.3)".

Maybe, like Bobby said, the obfuscation is a better way.
But hiding the source code is often a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

OCRA can build Ruby executables for Windows. You can check it out at: http://ocra.rubyforge.org/

Answer (score 0):

[RubyScript2Exe](http://www.erikveen.dds.nl/rubyscript2exe/) is probably what you are looking for. It should meet all of your needs, but supposedly generates a large executable under Windows because of static linking with cygwin.

Comment: No.  RubyScript2Exe will package up your source code, so the source code is most definitely visible.

Answer (score 0):

There's also the possibility to obfuscate the code, so that reading is getting close to impossible.

Comment: @Fabiano PS: Perl, the only language which is *after* RSA-Encryption more readable. ;)